# Android NavController: onResume/onPause callbacks reordering

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm struggling with very strange behavior of the android navigation library.

I've created a fragment with these callbacks (for showing fullscreen content, the actual system UI switching is implemented in `activity.setFullscreen`):

```
class FullscreenFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        activity.setFullscreen(true)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        activity.setFullscreen(false)
    }
    ...

}
```

Let's say we have 2 different fragments, `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` both inherit this `FullscreenFragment`.

The problem appears when I navigate from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` using `NavController.navigate` method - in this case `FragmentB.onResume` is being called BEFORE `FragmentA.onPause`. This leads to the fullscreen mode being disabled when transition is completed. The same happens when I navigate back from `FragmentB` to `FragmentA` - the `FragmentA.onResume` goes before `FragmentB.onPause`.

I suspect this is happening due to the implementation of `androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator` which calls `ft.setReorderingAllowed(true);` inside `public NavDestination navigate` method, just before committing fragment transaction.

What's the reason of this call being hardcoded inside the actual private implementation? Is there any way to overcome this issue (apart from implementing custom FragmentNavigator) and use natural lifecycle callbacks order?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could increment a counter in `onResume` and decrement in `onPause` and then only `setFullscreen(false)` when it equals zero.

For example:

```
class FullscreenFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    private int fragmentCount = 0;
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (fragmentCount == 0) {
            activity.setFullscreen(true);
        }
        fragmentCount++;
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        fragmentCount--;
        if (fragmentCount == 0) {
            activity.setFullscreen(false);
        }
    }
    ...

}
```